# Adding A Pointer To A Class Instance From The End Of One Vector To Another

Tags: c++, class, pointers, object, vector

So in the program there is a vector called called cardDeck which contains multiple pointers to instances of a class called Card:

```
std::vector<Card*> cardDeck;
```

Likewise there is a second vector called charCards also containing multiple pointers to instances of a class called card:

```
std::vector<Card*> charCards;
```

Part of the program functionality is to add the pointer to the card class instance from the end of the cardDeck vector to the end of the charCards vector:

```
charCards.push_back(cardDeck.back());                                                                               //Add the card selected from the deck to the Player's vector of initialisation cards
```

So for example if you start with the first card:

[image]

And then add a second card, instead of displaying the first card aligned with the second like so which is what SHOULD happen:

[image]

Instead only the second card (ie. the most recent card added to the vector) is rendered to the screen:

[image]

The question is - why do the sprites belonging to the card class instances preceeding the last instance in the charCards vector stop rendering when a new one is added?

Comment: Can you clarify "loss of data"?

Comment: Essentially I am using SFML to represent graphics in a game and each card class instance contains a sprite used to represnt it visually - each pointer to a card class instance in the cardDeck vector has an initialised sprite representing it, and the render function iterates through each instance and renders its sprite. Problem is only the last card class instance in the vector is rendered suggesting a loss of data when the card is transferred from one vector to the other.

Answer (score 2):

Somewhere, in code you're not showing us, you're creating a pointer to a local variable, and pushing that pointer into the container. Then, you're doing it again. And again.

Thing is, those are *all* dangling pointers, and they probably even contain the same address (though this is not guaranteed). That's why you're seeing the same values "in" every element.

- Don't store pointers, or
- Don't store dangling pointers.

Comment: But for example in another function in the program there is a loop which renders the sprites belonging to pointers to class instances which are stored in another vector, the rendering loop looking like this: for          (int i = 0; i < theMagi().size(); i++)
 {
  window.draw(theMagi()[i]->getCharacter());
 }                                                                                                          The thing is in this case all of the magi sprites render but when rendering the cards above, the render function looks the exact same and yet does not work so it appears there is an

Comment: issue with transferring the pointer to the class instance from one vector to another and it would be great to know what it is.

Comment: @Enchanter I'm sure it would but without actually showing us a testcase we cannot possibly have any idea what is wrong.

Comment: @Enchanter There's still no testcase. How can we debug code we can't see?